# Resize ubuntu 16.04 KVM Hard drive

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm currently doing the following process on the Host

```
mv vm.qcow2 vm.qcow2.bak
qemu-img create -f qcow2 addon.qcow2 +100G
cat vm.qcow2.bak addon.qcow2 >> vm.qcow2
```

This works, but when I book up the VM it still shows the old hard drive size?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of commands you've used results in a new image file with the *original*, un-resized content, and some new content is appended but entirely inaccessible.

In order to resize a QCOW2 disk image, you should use `qemu-img resize` instead. For example:

```
qemu-img resize vm.qcow2 +100G
```

There's no need to `cat` anything.

Keep in mind that this only changes the size of the virtual disk; you still need to use partitioning and filesystem tools to resize the virtual disk partitions and the filesystems contained on the virtual disk.